# Firebase Storage: Download a file from storage without download uri

Tags: android, ios, firebase-storage

Are the storage file downloads, done using `StorageReference.getStream()` in Android and `FIRStorageReference.dataWithMaxSize` in iOS, still using the download uri approach under the hood, that uses the unguessable token at the end of the uri?

My requirements forbid us to expose such urls to world, so the question is:

Does the file download, done using the methods above, generate the "unguessable" url for the file?

Links to questions in github:

- https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/865
- https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/3962

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no download URLs in play if you don't generate one. The Cloud Storage SDKs don't use those type of URLs internally for transfers.

Answer (score 0):

U can use [Storage Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start) to restrict access to the files, that way even if download uri is exposed, if the rules u set are not met the files will be inaccessible

Comment: That's not true. If you generate a download url, the resource is accessible through that link, regardless of any storage rules.